# What went wrong with driver setup on fresh install?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, additional-drivers

I just did a clean install of 22.04. The first thing I did after signing in for the first time was go to the Additional Drivers app to get the proprietary drivers for my Nvidia 2060 Super, I selected the newest drivers and rebooted. This time when it booted there was a huge amount of text output for just a second before login (I have a picture but it's poor quality and not very informative, the repeated string that stands out most is to do with "nvidia_modeset"). The Additional Drivers app shows the proprietary driver as being installed, but I checked the system info and the graphics section now said "llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)" where it typically says the name of the card. Another section read "To be filled by OEMTo be filled by OEM" repeated like that, but I'm not sure if that was relevant to the gpu problem. Where to begin with this?

Comment: Maybe the first thing to do after an install is to update all the packages before installing any new ones.  sudo apt update  then sudo apt upgrade

Comment: I did an upgrade after the reboot, but it didn't make any difference after the fact.